# Marking C# 8 nullable reference types as "this can't be null"

Tags: c#, nullable, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I am trying the new nullable reference types C# 8.0. I have come to one tiny issue:

```cs
foreach(FileSystemAccessRule rule in directorySecurity.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)))
{
    // do something with rule
}
```

This shows a warning since the compiler thinks the `rule` *could* be `null`, which it never will be.

My current fix is this:

```cs
foreach(FileSystemAccessRule? rule in directorySecurity.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)))
{
    if (rule == null) continue;
    // do something with rule
}
```

But I would be much happier with a fix, like `[NeverNull]FileSystemAccessRule rule` or something like that. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Why do think then it never be null? Have you checked the actual implementation of `GetAccessRules` method? You can easily fix it with null-forgiving operator `!`, like `rule!`

Comment: Related issues which cover this case: [#3045](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/3045), [#3214](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/3214)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski 
From the reference (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/1ef6853d86f1534a.html) it seems GetRules will always return a collection, but there will never be "null" entries inside.

Comment: @MuhKuh you are looking at .NET FW sources, for .net core sources you should look at https://source.dot.net/ or official github repo. C# 8 is supported only in .NET Core 3.x

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski thanks for that. canton7 seems to have the open issue from microsoft which directs this problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if `AuthorizationRuleCollection` doesn't declare the nullability, or declares them as nullable: the compiler is right to complain. You can use the dammit operator, though, if you're sure:

```cs
rule!.DoTheThing();
```

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/3214) (at time of writing) to perhaps change this rule slightly in the future.

Comment: Thank you for using the correct terminology, instead of the made-up "null-forgiving operator" nonsense ;)

Comment: It's official, used at [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/nullable-reference-types#checking-of-nullable-references), perfectly valid term.. which I heard today for the first time.

Comment: @MarcGravell Can you add this link to the ongoing discussion to your post in case something changes in the future: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/3214
I will accept your answer as solution.